# Can "nepotist" mean the recipient of nepotism?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I'm looking for a word that describe someone who benefits from nepotism.

My initial thought was "nepotist," but I've only ever seen that word used to refer to the giver of benefits, not the recipient. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nepotist) defines it simply as "one who practices nepotism," but I think its a bit ambiguous as to whether the family member receiving the benefits is actually "practicing" nepotism.

So can "nepotist" be used to refer to the recipient of benefits? If not, are there other phrases or words I could use?

Comment: This is why we use phrases like "benefited by nepotism" so that the meaning is clear.

Comment: Short answer: **no**, because all dictionaries I consulted show "nepotism" being practiced as *exclusively* by the one in power in bestowing favors; *not* "practice" of receiving such favors.  See, e.g. [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/nepotism), [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=nepotism), [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nepotism), [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nepotism), etc.

Comment: With the above being said, the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/126151?redirectedFrom=nepotism#eid) does list one sense, marked *rare* and long obsolete (**1680**!) as "*The advantages, or opportunities for advancement, enjoyed by a pope's nephew. Obs. rare.*" So back in the 17th century, the word was once used this way (though exclusively for papal nepotism).

Comment: @DanBron That is under 'nepotism'. Under 'nepotist' all examples seem to refer to the giver.

Comment: @Dan Brown, those are definitions for "nepotism". it is not completely clear in any of those sources who the "nepotist" is. I believe it could refer to either.

Answer (score -2):

Nepotee, since the root nepote is "nephew" and it is assumed the receiver is more important than the provider.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It was not my downvote, but your answer would be strengthened by providing examples in the wild, or a dictionary reference, as this usage is rare and thus many will find it suspect. I encourage you to review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on submitting good answers.

Comment: even if this is concocted I fully support this neologism. it's simple, fulfils a need, fits with the existing language conventions well, and doesn't encroach on occupied territory